# Can I call addto from addtocart

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I have a scenario in which i need to call `addto.phtml` from `addtocart.phtml`. I used the following code in `media.phtml` and it worked but its not working for addtocart.

```
<?php echo $this->getParentBlock()->getHtml('addto'); ?>
```

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to make some changed in `catalog.xml` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can call template any where but it required block class as there some method from block class call on that template.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view')->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/addto.phtml')->toHtml();
```

You can use above syntax in media or addtocart.

Hope this will help!

Comment: it worked great, thanx :)

Comment: Glad. it's help you. Happy coding.